# UNION and LIMIT 1 clarification

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a terrible doubt.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id,fatherID FROM comments WHERE fatherID IS NULL 
 UNION
SELECT id,fatherID FROM comments WHERE fatherID IS NOT NULL 
 LIMIT 1
```

(Note the limit 1 applies to the union, not to only the second query)
(Note2: IS NULL, and IS NOT NULL are just an example, they can be a random string too)

With this limit 1 I am sure that this kind of query will return the row from the first query all the time?

Or even if both query returns something it can happen that the LIMIT 1 get the row coming from the second query?

I am asking this because If i run that query (wtihtou limit 1) I get this results

http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/5212/immaginejv.jpg

When I would except something like this (First all the rows with `fatherid = null`, then the other):

http://img847.imageshack.us/img847/479/immaginehx.jpg

Comment: SQL does not imply an order unless you specify one.  The union command combines the two results and then eliminates duplicates.  There is no implied concept of first or second result set

Comment: I thought about it once again and realized that your table does not seem to contain NULLs in fatherID at all. It seems to contain empty strings instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order of returned results is (by default) undefined. If you want them ordered in a specific manner, use `ORDER BY`, it was made to do exactly this.

Comment: I think it's this way for most, if not all, database system. It's not like it is really unexpected behavior.

Comment: IMO it's easy to confuse this particular behaviour. Just looking at the SQL someone could think that First there is the returnset of the first query then the returnset of the second query. (I thought this too)

Comment: SQL usually operates on 'sets' (union, difference, exclusion, …), and sets do not by definition have an order.

Answer (score 2):

I have a question regarding your query. Why you would require this query? You are nothing but selecting all rows by making union of both opposite queries i.e

```
fatherID IS NULL OR NOT NULL
```

How can duplicate rows will present in result by this union query?

```
SELECT id, fatherID 
FROM comments 
WHERE fatherID IS NULL 

UNION

SELECT id, fatherID 
FROM comments 
WHERE fatherID IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 1
```

You can get result `(First all the rows with fatherid = null, then the other):` directly by this query:

```
SELECT id, fatherID 
FROM comments 
ORDER By fatherID
```

Updated answer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         id, fatherID 
     FROM 
         comments 
     WHERE 
         fatherID = 'somerandomstring1'

     UNION

     SELECT 
         id, fatherID 
     FROM 
         comments 
     WHERE 
         fatherID = 'somerandomstring2') combined_comments
ORDER BY 
    combined_comments.fatherID
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: because it was just an example, in reality the first query is `fatherID = 'somerandomstring1'` and second query is `fatherID = 'somerandomstring2'`

Comment: How would I know your reality? I have assumed everything from your question itself.

Comment: Your second query is perfectly fine in this case, But I am looking for a query that works generally (consider the string random)

Comment: Do you want union dynamic? You can put random string in variable and put it in where condition. Please elaborate more what actually you want..:-)

Comment: look at the second pic in my first post. I want that. (All result from first query first then all result from second query)

Comment: Do you mean fatherID can be array of strings? I am not getting much from picture.

Comment: it's really easy to understand. I have a query, `QUERY1`, and another query `QUERY2` Now I want a recordset containg first the records coming from the first query than the record coming from the second query... `QUERY1 UNION QUERY2` Anyway if you don't get this time again, i suggest you to delete this answer because is OT

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6141/discussion-between-somnath-muluk-and-yes123)